# How to run a crawler with ASP Core, service interaction and lifetime question

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, web-crawler

I developped a web crawler using ASP Core 3.1 App.

Following good practices I've gathered over the Internet, I splitted the *Downloader Service*, responsible for requesting webpages and storing them once downloaded into a Database, and the *Webpage Consolidation Service*, responsible for taking raw HTML webpages and consolidate them into useful data.

Since pages to be crawled are dependant of previously crawled webpages, the communication between those two services goes two ways through a database, achieving a good decoupling of services :

- The *Webpage Consolidation Service* fills URL to be crawled into the DB, and collect downloaded HTML
- The *Downloader Service* gathers URL from the DB and fills HTML once downloading is performed

I face multiple technical challenges and I feel my design is not optimal for various reasons.

1. Both *Downloader* and *Webpage Consolidation* Services **are registered as Singleton into the Services Container**. The underlying reason is that despite the App as a whole is designed as an API (to start the crawler, stop it, fetch some crawled data), those services run in the background for a much longer life time than an API request or even a session. I know that Singleton pattern can lead to problems but I have no better idea to run the crawler. **What problems should I expect and is there any better suited way of designing those services?**
2. In order to achieve *continous* operation, both services is started as a non-awaited asynchronous operations, and runs an infinite loop querying the database. The main problem I face with this design is that in case **any exception is raised during the process, for example a failing download** the exception doesn't bubble up anymore to the calling method (there is none) and the exception can potentially be run undefinitely.

I am convinced there are plenty of *bad* things to say about the way the App is designed, please be indulgent and point me to the correct resources if any. I am not sure neither if this post is compliant to Forum Rules (too broad question?), kindly delete it if not.

Here is a simplified version of the crawler :

```
public class APIController : Controller //API Controller starting and stopping the crawler
{
    private DownloaderService _downloaderService;
    private WebpageConsolidationService _consolidationService;

    public APIController(DownloaderService downloaderService, WebpageConsolidationService consolidationService) {
        _downloaderService = downloaderService;
        _consolidationService = consolidationService;
    }


    public IActionResult StartCrawler() {
        if (!_downloaderService.DownloaderStarted) {
            Task t1 = _downloaderService.StartDownloaderAsync(); //non awaited task
        }
        if (!_consolidationService.ConsolidationStarted) {
            Task t2 = _consolidationService.StartWebpageConsolidationAsync(); //non awaited task
        }
        return Ok();
    }

    public IActionResult StopCrawler() {
        if (_downloaderService.DownloaderStarted) {
            _downloaderService.DownloaderStarted = false;
        }
        if (_consolidationService.ConsolidationStarted) {
            _consolidationService.ConsolidationStarted = false;
        }
        return Ok();
    }

}


public class DownloaderService //Singleton
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory;

    public DownloaderService(ApplicationDbContext context, IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
    {
        _context = context;
        this.scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
    }

    public bool DownloaderStarted { get; set; }

    public async Task StartDownloaderAsync()
    {
        DownloaderStarted = true;
        while (DownloaderStarted)
        {
            using (var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope()) {
                var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();

                string url = context.Webpages.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Downloaded == false)?.Url;
                if(url==null) continue;

                //Download the webpage here
                Webpage webpage = await DowloadWebpageAsync(url);
                webpage.Downloaded = true;
                context.Webpages.Add(webpage);
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();

                if (context.Webpages.Any(x => x.Downloaded == false)) await Task.Delay(10000); //in case there is no more webpage to crawl now
            }
        }
    }
}

public class WebpageConsolidationService //Singleton
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory;

    public bool ConsolidationStarted { get; set; }

    public WebpageConsolidationService(ApplicationDbContext context, IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory) {
        _context = context;
        this.scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
    }

    public async Task StartWebpageConsolidationAsync()
    {
        ConsolidationStarted = true;
        while (ConsolidationStarted) {
            using (var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope()) {
                var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();

                Webpage toBeProcessed = context.Webpages.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Processed == false && x.Downloaded == true);
                if (toBeProcessed == null) continue;

                //Consolidate the webpage here
                Webpage[] otherWebpages = await ProcessWebpage(toBeProcessed);
            context.Webpages.AddRange(otherWebpages);

            await context.SaveChangesAsync();

                if (context.Webpages.Any(x => x.Processed == false && x.Downloaded==true)) await Task.Delay(10000); //in case there is no more webpage to crawl now
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A crawler should be run as a generic host instead of a web host(asp.net core application). In another words your download service and webpage consolidation service should be 2 different .NET core application and there communication should use either message queue or other cross process communication way.

For the 2ed question you mentioned, every download should be a individual thread or task, and the thread or task should be taken from a pool so that you won't consume too many memory. Write log when there is exception in the downloader.

There is actually no official documents about how to write a crawler in .net core since this is more like a personal lab project, I'm sharing my [own](https://github.com/xboxeer/NScrapy) crawler framework here so you can have some idea of how to write a distributed crawler(with individual downloader, storing service, etc). Of course this one is not a perfect one, the function of this framework is little more complex than your crawler(I basically copied the idea from Scrapy), and it's written based on .net core 2.0 so it can not utilize the latest feature of .net core 3.1. however I believe you can still get some benefit from it.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and your sharing. I agree that a web host is not ideal, but it can be easily hosted into the Cloud (Azure Web Apps for example), can a generic host be deployed as easily? I get your point for project split, but it complexifies a lot the overall project.

Comment: to deploy a generic host, you can use some devops tools like azure devops, github action, jenkins or simply copy pasted the output binary to any place then run it using dotnet yourprogramname.exe